# how to use scipy and opencv in my lambda function for a big size of package.zip

Tags: aws-lambda

I have to use scipy and opencv in my lambda function. For this purpose I'm creating a layer consisting of both scipy and opencv. But I'm unable to create such a layer due to the big size of package.zip (containing scipy and opencv dependencies). Can you please suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe creating two separate layers, one for `scipy` and one for `opencv` would work.